# Django Template Date filter not working on Pandas Datetime Index in Table

Tags: django, pandas

I am not able to format a date using the Django filter.

Anything I add results in nothing, example:  month|date:"M-Y"

I am passing in a dataframe after doing a groupby.

```
df2 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M"))[["gross", "net"]].sum()

               gross      net
month                         
2013-02-28   2570.33  1105.20
2013-03-31   8964.05  2041.51
2013-04-30   4763.38  2048.15
```

The context being passed.

```
context = {
    'title'    : '{} Analysis'.format ( p.name ),
    'data'     :  df2.to_records ()
}
```

It is a simple table, but if I add any date filter to the i.month - I get nothing.

```
{% for i in data %}

        <tr>
          <td>{{ i.month }}</td>
          <td>{{ i.gross|floatformat:"0"|intcomma }}</td>
          <td>{{ i.net|floatformat:"0"|intcomma }}</td>
        </tr>

      {% endfor %}
```

This is the none filtered output.

[image]

I have never had such a problem before formatting a date. is it because it is the index value?

Thanks so much.

Comment: try converting the index into a column and see if that works `df2['month'] = df2.index`

Comment: Nope.  Same results.

Comment: I just used pandas to format that I wanted based on your idea. df2 [ 'month' ] = df2.month.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

Comment: this is also a much more efficient solution, as django filters are known to be inefficient and definitely no where near to pandas in terms of performance